# Not Sure Why Apache Server Automatically Put A Site In Frame

Tags: html, iframe, apache2, reverse-proxy

Is there a configuration somewhere in Apache server that causes all pages to be in a Frame? I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Platform</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="Platform">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://someURL" frameborder="0">
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize="">
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 01 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

It essentially takes the meta tag out and use it for parent page and have everything else in the content of the page in the Frame.

Please let me know if you have any idea. I can't reproduced it locally on my laptop so I figured there has to be some configuration that doesn't match, but I have no idea where to even start looking. The same configuration for reverse proxy is used.

Comment: Checked your .htaccess and modrewrite configurations?

Comment: We don't have .htaaccess file and no rewrite

Comment: That's a frame, not an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a configuration somewhere in Apache server that causes all pages to be in an iFrame?

Not that I've ever heard of.

This sort of framing is typical of sites that have bought a domain name and are using it via Masking instead of using proper DNS hosting.

Comment: It does sound like the old *.tk tld's.

Comment: This actually sounds about right. Will check if it's done properly in godaddy.com account.

Comment: It was definitely to do with masking, but a little more involved. Essentially, the configuration wasn't matching with the reverse proxy. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Running into the same issue -- how did you resolve this on the GoDaddy side?

Comment: Oh ! Never tought it could come from there... Shame on me and thanks a lot !